# Use Google Map in Blackberry application

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, gps, jsr179

Can anyone tell me how to use Google maps in blackberry application development instead of Blackberry map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recently I had an idea to use [Google Maps website](http://maps.google.com) from [Browser.Field](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8540/Display_content_in_BB_Browser_field_565587_11.jsp) but it's not possible since GMaps are based on JavaScript and it's badly supported by Blackberry native Browser.

Actually there are 2 ways of using Google Maps on Blackberry:

- install [Google Maps Mobile](http://www.google.com/mobile/products/maps.html#p=default) application (see [example of use](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/143263-heres-how-start-google-maps-landmark.html))
- use [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to generate and send image on device request. This will require server-side implementation and [Sign Up for the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example:

The Form to view the Google Maps Static image:

```
public class frmMap extends Form implements CommandListener {

    Command _back;
    MIDlet midlet;
    Form dis;

    public frmMap(String title, ImageItem img, MIDlet m, Form d){
        super(null);

        this.midlet = m;
        this.dis = d;

        _back = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 1);
        addCommand(_back);
        append(img);
        setCommandListener(this);        
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if(c == _back){
            Display.getDisplay(midlet).setCurrent(dis);
        }
    }

}
```

The class inet class to download the static image:

```
public class INETclass implements Runnable {

    private String _location = null;
    private HttpConnection inet;
    private Pispaal _m;
    public String url = null;

    public INETclass(String location, Pispaal m){
        _location = location;
        _m = m;        
    }

    public void run() {
        try
        {
            //Setup the connection
            inet = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
            inet.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            int rc = inet.getResponseCode();

            //Responsecode controleren
            if(rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
                //Open input stream to read the respone
                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(inet.openInputStream());                
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                int ch;
                long len = -1;
                byte[] buffer = null;
                if(_location == null){
                    len = is.available();
                }

                if(len != -1){
                    if(_location == null){
                        buffer = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
                    }else{
                        while((ch = is.read()) != -1){
                            sb.append((char)ch);
                        }
                    }
                }
                is.close();

                if(_location == null){
                    _m.OnINETComplete(buffer);
                }else{
                    _m.Alert(sb.toString());
                }
            }else{
                _m.Alert("URL " + url + " geeft response code: " + rc);
                try
                {
                    inet.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    _m.Alert("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _m.Alert("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(inet != null){ inet.close(); }  
                Thread.currentThread().join(); //Making sure this thread dies
            }catch(Exception e){
                _m.Alert("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Button action that starts the download and the callback action that loads the form to view the image

```
public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        synchronized(c){
            String loc = _location.getText();
            if(loc.indexOf(",") > 0){
                //if(c == _strCommand){                
                    //INETclass inet = new INETclass(loc, this);
                    //Thread tInet = new Thread(inet);
                    //tInet.start();
                    //Alert("Locatie word doorgestuurd. Even geduld");
                //}else 
                if(c == _mapView){
                    INETclass inet = new INETclass(null, this);
                    inet.url = "http://www.qeueq.com/gmap.php?location=" + this.lat + "," + this.lon + "&size=" + this.width + "x" + this.height + ";deviceside=true";
                    Thread tInet = new Thread(inet);
                    tInet.start();
                }
            }else{
                Alert("GPS locatie is nog niet beschikbaar.");
            }
        }
    }

public void UpdateLocation(double lat, double lon){
       String location = lat + "," + lon;
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lon = lon;
       synchronized(location){
           _location.setText(location);
            INETclass inet = new INETclass(location, this);
            Thread tInet = new Thread(inet);
            tInet.start();           
       } 
    }
```

Refine and edit the code so it fits your needs. Took me some time to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now to use Google Maps instead of BlackBerry maps with our own data like in the image.
[image]

If you're looking to use google maps to show your own locations/markers you can invoke google maps using `ApplicationDescriptor` from your application. Check for google maps on device using `CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("GoogleMaps");` it returns an integer where non zero means it is available. Then you can add locations in your `KML` file, you can even customize location pointers using KML file tags.

The ***[example](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/143263-heres-how-start-google-maps-landmark.html)*** as linked by Max allows a single marker only. So a KML file becomes necessary if multiple markers are to be added.

You may look at the simple tutorial *[**here**](http://codehunk.blogspot.in/2013/05/google-maps-on-blackberry-add-location.html)* for beginners.