# Blackberry - error on open Google Maps in browser

Tags: browser, google-maps, blackberry, gps

The Google Map doesn't render in the BlackBerry Simulator.
My application has a "View Map" button which on click calls a Google Map web URL.
The error is "ThrownValue in ExecuteScript ReferenceError:GMap2 is not defined in BlackBerry"

I did enable the JavaScript support in the Browser configuration

Device Target:Up to Bold
Blackberry JDE 4.5

Any solution ideas will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Google Map Mobile on Blackberry, then use it.
Read
[How to use Google Map in Blackberry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387688/how-to-use-google-map-in-blackberry-application)
[BlackBerry and map based apps like Yelp and Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615520/blackberry-and-map-based-apps-like-yelp-and-google-map)
**UPDATE**
I don't believe google maps can be opened with browser or browserField on blackberry.
I've stated my position in links that we have to use GMaps app or Static with server implementation.
But if there is other possibility, I really would be appreciate to know it.

Comment: Thank you Sir,I have read these posts earlier too.
Please read my reply and help me figure out a solution