# BlackBerry:Accessing Google Maps API's on Blackberry platform?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application, which should be able to access Google Maps and it's API set on Blackberry platform? 
I want to programmatically,
1. search for current location information
2. Places information like famous places, malls, restaurants and other details etc. 
using Google Map API's.

How do i access Google Map API's to achieve this in Blackberry platform? If not possible,
How do i achieve this in Blackberry platform in any other way? 
From which version of Blackberry(SDK and Device version), these things will be possible to implement?
I googled it, and found some links related this like below, those doesn't helped me.

1. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Google-Map/td-p/21412;jsessionid=760CF8E4A2DAA4B5A31BC2ACD1F09998
2. [BlackBerry and map based apps like Yelp and Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615520/blackberry-and-map-based-apps-like-yelp-and-google-map)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe this refrence answer will help you 


 [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701831/google-map-is-not-showing-in-blackberry-browser

Answer (score 1):

i have implemented the google static map with navigation control, please find the code here http://www.mediafire.com/?sce8x11y9o9jcs3 add comments and update back.. thanks