# Google Map is not showing in Blackberry Browser

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Hello Everyone,
               I am trying to open Google-Map URL in BlackBerry Browser , 
 but unfortunately it's not showing the Google-Map.
 The URL is working fine in other OS(Android , Iphone , Windows)

here is the URL : https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=DT4+8DX&daddr=DT6+3JP
 and here is my Blackberry Code

```
String address = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=DT4+8DX&daddr=DT6+3JP";
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(address);

// I also tried with this approach 
String address = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=DT4+8DX&
address = getUrlEncodedString(address);

Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(address);

private String getUrlEncodedString(String hsURL)
{
    URLEncodedPostData urlEncoder = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    urlEncoder.setData(hsURL);
    hsURL = urlEncoder.toString();
    return hsURL;
}
```

please let me know , why this is not showing G-Map.

Answer (score 0):

I try url like this in Nokia and Blackberry. In this platforms i found that this platforms dont support in call through url. I think that url is supported only in android (native to gogle maps) and Iphone that develop support to google maps through url.

> Note
>
> If you try call google maps through url in Blackberry browser, the answer that
>   you get is Google page search

Comment: thanks for the reply ...  Is there any another way to show G-Map in Blackberry Browser ?