# Integrated maps (with location markers, etc.) in BlackBerry apps - viable options?

Tags: blackberry, android-mapview, blackberry-jde, nutiteq

I have heard rumors that the use of a MapField or MapView in a BlackBerry app typically presents a problem because carriers such as AT&T and Verizon in the US have locked down the devices so as to not make those API's available or usable. I have three questions:

1) I am new to BlackBerry development. What's the difference between MapField and MapView and their respective availabilities? Are they related or different?

2) Are there actual known carrier restrictions that prevent / prohibit the use of MapField and/or MapView?

3) If there are known carrier issues, what are the best alternatives? So far I've found the following options: a) use of a Browser.Field with [Google Static Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) (good suggestions from these StackOverflow questions: [How to use Google Map in BlackBerry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387688/how-to-use-google-map-in-blackberry-application) and [BlackBerry and map based apps like Yelp and Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615520/blackberry-and-map-based-apps-like-yelp-and-google-map)); b) license the [Nutiteq map API library](http://www.nutiteq.com/). Any other viable options I might be missing out on?

Thanks for your time in helping out a BlackBerry newbie.

Comment: nutiteq - 2000 euro isn't it too expensive for single app license? I think it is if map functionality is optional, like in some communication or social app

Comment: Yes, very expensive, and looking / hoping for alternatives.