# blackberry google map java code

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

how i add google map to my application.
when i click a button, then it open the google map.
how it can be done ?
give detailed explanation.
iam a fresher to blackberry programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whats going on your appllication but I hope this will help you.

[BlackBerry and map based apps like Yelp and Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615520/blackberry-and-map-based-apps-like-yelp-and-google-map)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

http://www.google.com/mobile/maps/#p=default

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/