# Impementation of google map in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have to develop an application which involves implementation of google map in blackberry.

Comment: is anybody dere for providing me the sample code of how to fire a event on click of list in blackberry ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google Map in Blackberry application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387688/how-to-use-google-map-in-blackberry-application)

Answer (score 1):

u can use Static google map api.. Follow the link

[Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)